# How many coefficients are in the expansion $(x + y + z)^{10}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, self-learning

I need to find the number of coefficients in the expansion $(x + y + z)^{10}$.

I had this exercise on a recent assignment.

The answer I gave is: $3^{10} = \binom {3 + 10 - 1}{10} = \binom{12}{10} = 132$, but my tutor says the answer is 66.

I don't know where I went wrong and, therefore, I don't know how to get 66. Can someone show me where I went wrong with this exercise?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calculating your binomial coefficients? Note that $3^{10} = 59049 \neq 132$, though $\binom{12}{10} = 66$.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $(x+y+z)^{10}$? Because then I would agree with $66$ as the answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant $(x + y +z)^{10}$. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I just rewrote my answer using: $C(12, 10) = \binom {12!}{10!(12-10)!} = \binom {12!}{10!2!} = 66$. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: By coefficients do you mean *terms*? Also, you had the right answer, but you miscalculated ${12 \choose 10} = 66 \neq 132$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the number of coefficients of $(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_m)^n$ is ${n+m-1\choose m-1}={n+m-1\choose n}$.

This can be shown with the [Stars and Bars methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). Basically you need to count the number of ways that it is possible to add $m$ nonnegative integers to get $n$.

Comment: I think this is the method I tried to use. Should I have used this instead: $\binom {10 + 3-1}{10} = \binom {12}{10} = \binom {12!}{10!(12-10)!} = \binom {(12)(11)(10!)}{(10!)(2!)} = (6)(11) = 66$

Comment: Yes, that's right. To make things a little simpler though, you could also cancel the $10!$s in your comment above.

Answer (score 2):

You can write
\begin{align}
(x+y+z)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k(y+z)^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{j}x^k y ^j z^{n-k-j} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \frac{n!}{k!j!(n-k-j)!}x^k y ^j z^{n-k-j}
\end{align}
using Newton's Binomial formula twice (or the multinomial formula once, equivalently). This shows you have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} 1 = \sum_{k=0}^n (n+1-k) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} = \binom{n+2}{n}
$$
coefficients in the expansion.